# What's the difference between UnicodeEncoding and Encoding.Unicode?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

For UTF-16 encoding, C# has both System.Text.UnicodeEncoding and System.Text.Encoding.Unicode. What's the difference between the two and when should I use each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` is a property that returns an instance of `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` with [documented *default* settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use that, if the defaults fit your use case. Otherwise, create a custom instance of the [`UnicodeEncoding` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the [UnicodeEncodingClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) which has all the functionality to work with UTF-16 encoded data. The second one, [Encoding.Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx), is a property that returns a cached instance of the UnicodeEncodingClass much in the same way that Encoding.UTF8 or Encoding.ASCII does for their respective encodings.

If you need to customize the instance in some way (changing the byteorder to big endian perhaps) then you should create your own instance of [UnicodeEncodingClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx), otherwise you can use the [Encoding.Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) shortcut.